# Display only last array element

Tags: php, virtuemart

It's for Virtuemart, but it's more basic php stuff...

I need some help/hint...

What I want to do - I want to display TaxAmount sum for only discounts with some id in Virtuemart Cart (it is -> I want do show seperatelly discounts per discount type).

Here is what I'm trying so far:

```
foreach ($this->cart->products as $pkey => $prow)
{
 if ($prow->product_discount_id==2) 
 {
  $discounts= $this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey]['discountAmount'];
  $discountss+=$discounts;
  echo "<span class='priceColor2'>" . $discountss . "</span>" ;
 }
}
```

Bt the problem is that it's echo'ing all discounts sums (while foreach is true)... How I can display just last element or maybe better use different solution?

TNX!

Comment: I would start with the PHP manual http://us2.php.net/array_pop

Answer (score 0):

You should take the `echo` out of the foreach loop.

```
$discountss = 0;
foreach ($this->cart->products as $pkey => $prow) {
    if ($prow->product_discount_id==2) {
        $discountss += $this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey]['discountAmount'];
    }
}

echo "<span class='priceColor2'>" . $discountss . "</span>" ;
```

Comment: This is the solution! TNX! Stupid mistake...never should work when head already overloaded! ;-D

Answer (score -1):

if you want display last element from array u can use end(). For example:

```
 $fruits = array('apple', 'banana', 'cranberry');
 echo end($fruits); // cranberry
```

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% sure I follow you, but you can use array_pop() to return the last element of an array.

```
$myArray = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
$fruit = array_pop($myArray);

echo $fruit; //echoes 'orange'
```

See the [manual](https://www.php.net/array_pop) for more information.